# How to Change the icon which displays on the datalist input in HTML? Hiding is possible , but can i change it to some other icons, Like arrow-down?

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

This is the code for hiding it. How can I change the icon to some other icons?

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to hide the icon using `opacity:0`, then you can add your own icon. In this simple I'm using [`fontawesome`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/calendar/) calendar icon.

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity:0;
}

input {
  position:relative;  
}

input:before {
  content: "\f073";
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="date" />
```